# rfc 6939 support for dhcpv6 relay

Tags: ipv6, isc-dhcp, dhcp-option, dhcpv6

isc-dhcp-server now supports rfc6939 as of version 4.3, and I would like to be able use it as it is quite nice to be able to just use the mac address to identify dhcpv6 clients.  However, I can't seem to find a dhcpv6 relay that supports rfc 6939, option 79, or dhcp6.client-linklayer-addr, other than the one on a Cisco switch as in this article:
https://insinuator.net/2015/02/is-rfc-6939-support-finally-here-checking-the-implementation-of-the-client-link-layer-address-option-in-dhcpv6/

I imagine the isc-dhcp-relay should be able to do this since isc-dhcp-server does, but it doesn't out of the box and the man page on ubuntu 16.04 server doesn't mention a way of turning it on.  Does anyone either know how to enable this option, or know of a dhcpv6 relay that is installable on linux that does support it.

Comment: I have heard that Brocade supports it as well. I know that existing Linux DHCPv6 servers and relays don't support it (some fake support by assuming MAC addresses embedded in link-local address are correct). If you find one that does: let me know! I haven't implemented it yet, but adding support for this is on my to-do list for DHCPKit :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pretty flat network without DHCPv6 relay just look at dhcpy6d (https://dhcpy6d.ifw-dresden.de). It takes MAC addresses from neighbor cache and not from link local address so they are really usable.

Support for RFC 6939 might come in the future.